# Oracle procedure updating all records

Tags: oracle, function, stored-procedures, oracle11g

Hi am trying to update specific records from table using stored procedure in Oracle,
but its updating all records instead of specific records.
Here is my EMP table before executing stored procedure

```
ID, NAME, DEPT, SAL
1   pc    New   100000000
2   pc1   qwe   1
3   pc2   New   2
4   pc4   asf   3
5   pc5   New   4
6   pc6   qwe   5
7   pc7   New   6
8   pc8   COMP  8
9   pc9   New   9
10  pc10  New   7
11  pc11  qwe   11
12  pc12  New   12
13  pc13  New   13
14  pc14  qwe   14
```

Function which checks for is EMP belongs to COMP department

```
create or replace FUNCTION ISCOMPGUY 
(
  EMPID IN NUMBER 
) RETURN NUMBER AS

dept varchar(20);

cursor getDept IS select dept from emp where id=EMPID;

BEGIN
    open getDept; FETCH getDept INTO dept;
    IF DEPT = 'COMP' THEN 
        return 1;
    ELSE
        return 0;
    END IF;
END ISCOMPGUY;
```

Procedure which updates record depending on ISCOMPGUY Function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPATEEMP AS 

isValid number :=0;

cursor getCompGuys IS select id from emp;-- where dept='COMP';
BEGIN
    for emp in getCompGuys loop
        isValid := iscompguy(emp.id);
        dbms_output.put_line ('isValid '|| emp.id || ' : ' || isValid );
        if isValid = 1 then
            dbms_output.put_line ('updating ' ||emp.id);
                UPDATE EMP set dept='IT' where id = emp.id;
        end if;        
     end loop;
END UPATEEMP;
```

But when I run procedure its updating all records
output of procedure and EMP table after execution of procedure

```
Connecting to the database testDB.
isValid 1 : 0
isValid 2 : 0
isValid 3 : 0
isValid 4 : 0
isValid 5 : 0
isValid 6 : 0
isValid 7 : 0
isValid 8 : 1
updating 8
isValid 9 : 0
isValid 10 : 0
isValid 11 : 0
isValid 12 : 0
isValid 13 : 0
isValid 14 : 0
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database testDB.

ID, NAME, DEPT, SAL
1   pc      IT  100000000
2   pc1     IT  1
3   pc2     IT  2
4   pc4     IT  3
5   pc5     IT  4
6   pc6     IT  5
7   pc7     IT  6
8   pc8     IT  8
9   pc9     IT  9
10  pc10    IT  7
11  pc11    IT  11
12  pc12    IT  12
13  pc13    IT  13
14  pc14    IT  14
```

Eventhough output says its updating only for emp.id=8, all records are getting updated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't leave opened cursors, like in your function "ISCOMPGUY". Close it.

Answer (score 2):

I may have just put a comment on this, but I consider it too important to say that your approach with cursors and function calls for such a simple operation is *absolutely inessential* and a *sub-optimal* solution.

It appears that what you actually want is an update statement like this.

```
UPDATE emp
    SET
        dept = 'IT'
    WHERE dept = 'COMP';
```

This is much efficient and performant than looping through all the values through a cursor and writing unnecessary code.

If at all you want to display which ids got updated, all you may need to do is to use a `RETURNING BULK COLLECT INTO` statement to store and fetch the ids from a collection.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE upateemp AS
    TYPE empidtyp IS
        TABLE OF emp.id%TYPE;
    empids   empidtyp;
BEGIN
    UPDATE emp
    SET
        dept = 'IT'
    WHERE dept = 'COMP' RETURNING id BULK COLLECT INTO empids; --store the updated ids in a collection

    FOR i IN 1..empids.count LOOP --loop through collection elements
        dbms_output.put_line('isValid ' || empids(i) ); 
    END LOOP;

END upateemp;
/
```

Execution

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
BEGIN
 EXEC upateemp;
END;
/
isValid 8


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing the database somewhat with this:

```
UPDATE EMP set dept='IT' where id = emp.id;
```

so what does emp.id equate to here? Does the system think that is the `emp` from the for loop, or is it the reference to the `EMP` table in the statement itself. I suspect it is putting the more local `emp` table reference first when it resolves it, in which case the update is asking to update where id = id, e.g. all rows.

I would change the alias on the loop variable as re-test

Answer (score 0):

Got is solved by taking emp.id in new variable and passing it to update command

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPATEEMP AS 

isValid number :=0;
eid number;

cursor getCompGuys IS select id from emp;-- where dept='COMP';
BEGIN
    for emp in getCompGuys loop
        isValid := iscompguy(emp.id);
        eid := emp.id;
        dbms_output.put_line ('isValid '|| emp.id || ' : ' || isValid );
        if isValid = 1 then
            dbms_output.put_line ('updating ' ||emp.id);
            UPDATE EMP set dept='IT' where id = eid;
        end if;        
     end loop;
END UPATEEMP;
```

Comment: well its better you change `for emp` to another name , because emp is table ,name 
 it another thing example `for ec in ..` by the way where are you adding the commit ?